# How to create and print precisely positioned template in Java? (For printing over existing forms.)

Tags: java, template-engine

In Java how do we print to a pre-printed template? We have pre-printed form with field names and blank spaces. From Java, I need to print data into the blank spaces.

These pre-printed forms are always of the same template. All the fields and blank spaces are of fixed dimensions. I know the exact position of each blank space i.e., the location of it from the left of the page, top of the page, length of the blank space etc.

We already have an application in .Net where we achieved using RDL(report definition language - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language). We are migrating to Java/mysql and was looking on how to achieve it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've used JasperReports (painful, but OK), and BIRT (absolutely hated it). But there are several other reporting tools for Java. Use google.

Comment: Is it better to use reports or just generate a PDF using something like PDFBox or Java iText? Any thoughts?